# Does RFC 5988 allow whitespace in the HTTP Link header?

Tags: http, http-headers, bnf, rfc822, rfc5988

Section 5 of [RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) defines the syntax of the Link header as follows:

```
Link           = "Link" ":" #link-value
link-value     = "<" URI-Reference ">" *( ";" link-param )
```

This specification uses augmented Backus-Naur Form (BNF) as defined in [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822).

If understand BNF correctly, the specification does not permit whitespace between the semicolon (`;`) and `link-param`. However, in the examples which appear in Section 5, there is whitespace between the two elements:

```
Link: <http://example.com/TheBook/chapter2>; rel="previous";
      title="previous chapter"

Link: </>; rel="http://example.net/foo"
```

I also observed whitespace in the Link header in Github's API which I consider one of the more standard-compliant APIs:

```
$ curl -s -I https://api.github.com/users/mitsuhiko/repos
...
Link: <https://api.github.com/user/7396/repos?page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/user/7396/repos?page=7>; rel="last"
```

Is whitespace supposed to be permissible? I can't find anything which provides evidence either way besides these examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is permissible; RFC 5988 uses ABNF as defined by RFC 2616, which has special rules for linear white space. See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5988.html#rfc.section.2.p.2 and https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.2.1:

> The grammar described by this specification is word-based. Except
>   where noted otherwise, linear white space (LWS) can be included
>   between any two adjacent words (token or quoted-string), and between
>   adjacent words and separators, without changing the interpretation of
>   a field. At least one delimiter (LWS and/or separators) MUST exist
>   between any two tokens (for the definition of "token" below), since
>   they would otherwise be interpreted as a single token.

FWIW, RFC 5988 has been obsoleted a few months ago anyway; see RFC 8288 (https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc8288.html) for the latest and greatest (specifically Section 3).

Comment: Before I accept this answer, can you quote the exact section that allows whitespace? I don't see it. Is it "White space is only significant in that indentation of continuation lines is used to indicate a rule definition that spans more than one line"?